# node js xray getting data from json file

Tags: node.js, x-ray

I am developing a Node Js application using X-Ray library and I want to get the data from a json file so here my code

```
const Xray = require('x-ray');
      const x = Xray({filters: filters})
       x(url, '.review', [{
            title    : '.a-size-baseif'
        }])
```

and here is what want I am trying to do instead:

```
const Xray = require('x-ray');
      const x = Xray({filters: filters})
       x(url, getdata.json)
```

so is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require("fs");
const Xray = require('x-ray');
      const x = Xray({filters: filters})
       x(url, '.review', [{
            title    : '.a-size-baseif'
        }])(function(err, Res){
    fs.writeFile('result.json', JSON.stringify(Res)); 
    })
```

mybe like that